# Moving from Microsoft Front Page 2003 to WordPress

Tags: html, installation

Existing web host vanished!! 
How move multi-paged photo-heavy performer fan site (mouseketeerlonnieburr.com) from Microsoft FrontPage 2003 to WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

1. Design your layout front-end.
2. Integrate it to WordPress. (Make it WordPress Theme)
3. Create custom post types and custom contents, custom page templates as per your requirements.
4. Buy new hosting & point your domain's nameserver to new host.
5. Upload your files & Enjoy. You've done it. ;)

Comment: All of that is not a process that will be easy. Lots of time to convert each page of the old site into a page of the new site. And lots of time to upload all the pix from the old place to the new place, and put the pix in the appropriate page.  But, it can be done. Just saying that it won't be a quick process.  It is possible to find a hosting place that will support FrontPage, though, so you could copy a backup of the site to a new hosting place. (I'm assuming you have backups.....)

Comment: well that is also an good option (finding hosting that supports frontpage). But many hosting providers already removed frontpage support from their hosting and others are also on their way to do so. So, for future updates and future supports it's good to convert frontpage site to WordPress or some other current platforms. Yes, it may take some time but we should be prepare for the future too, isn't it right?

Comment: I only suggested finding a FrontPage hosting place because their existing site 'vanished' (per OP). So that new hosting place would get them back online (assuming they had backups), and then they could start on the process of moving to a WP platform.

Comment: Agreed. That is the point too.